# Should I upgrade to EntityFrameWorkCore 5.x when using .Net Core 3.x?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-5

I have a multi-project solution that contains a data layer on .Net Standard 2.1 and a WebAPI on .Net Core 3.1. Currently, I have no plans to upgrade to .Net 5.x (Note: `Core` is removed in 5.x naming convention) because it is not LTS - that will be .Net 6.x. So, I will upgrade to 6.x when it comes out.

In one of my data layer solutions, the NuGet Package Manager is recommending that I upgrade `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameWorkCore` from `v3.1.8` to `v5.0.2`. It seems like the major version is moving in lockstep with the .Net major version (Note: 4.x is skipped in order to avoid confusion with the venerable .Net Framework 4.x). Should I follow the advice and upgrade?

Specifically, will this cause any problems with the .Net Core 3.1 WebAPI project? Generally, can I do this for other `Microsoft.*` packages that recommend upgrading to a 5.x version?

Comment: Unless you need EF Core 5 features just stay at 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bit the bullet and upgraded all of them. Everything works flawlessly and I am glad that I did it. There were a few breaking changes that needed to be dealt with. I recommend checking Microsoft's breaking change log here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio